# Docker composed services can't communicate by service name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

tldr: I can't communicate with a docker composed service by its service name in order to make requests to an api running in networked containers.

I have a single page application that makes requests to a json api. Its Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

A build process does it's thing and puts all the static assets in a dist directory which is then copied to the html directory of the nginx web server.

I have a mock json api powered by json-server. Its Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:7.10.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  badass-ui:
    image: mydocker-hub/badass-ui
    container_name: badass-ui
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  badderer-api:
    image: mydocker-hub/badderer-api
    container_name: badderer-api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I'm able to build both containers successfully, and am able to run "docker-compose up" with both containers running smoothly. Fetch requests from badass-ui to badderer-api:3000/users returns "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". Fetch requests to http://192.168.99.100:3000/users (or whatever the container IP may be) work fine. I thought by using docker compose I would be able to reference the name of a service defined in docker-compose.yml as a domain name, and that would enable communication between the containers via domain name. This doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with my docker-compose.yml? I'm on Windows 10 Home edition, using the tools that come with the Docker Quickstart terminal for Windows. I'm using docker-compose version 1.13.0, docker version 17.05.0-ce, docker-machine version 0.11.0 and VirtualBox 5.1.20.

Comment: Try adding `links:`  in your badass-ui yml, pointing to the API. In order to have an startup order. Do you make the request at the very beginning of the UI startup?

Comment: Yes, I do make a request at the very beginning of UI startup. I'll try adding links, although I thought they weren't necessary in 2.0. I'll also take a look at controlling start order using depends_on. Thanks for  pointing that out. Am I correct in thinking that I should be able to make calls to badderer-api:3000 from the baddass-ui container if they've been networked using docker-compose?

Comment: You are right about the pointing and networking. The `links` that I've proposed is equivalent to `depends_on`, both indicates the startup order. Try that. Or indeed, just for troubleshooting, try adding a sleep 5 seconds, as the first thing in your UI

Comment: Adding links and depends_on didn't work. Neither did adding a 5 second timeout to the UI (it's in JavaScript). I am able to curl the API from inside the UI container using the API container name as the domain name.

Comment: See this very simple example of what you are trying to do: https://pastebin.com/B48AkcJs. I don't know why it is not working in your js app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using docker-compose.yml version 2, links should not be necessary. Containers within a compose network should be able to resolve other compose containers by service name.

Reading the comments on your question it seems like the networking and host name resolution works, so it seems like the problem is in your web UI. I don't see you passing any type of configuration to the UI application saying where to find the api. Maybe there is a hard coded url to the api in your UI causing the error?

Edit:

Is your UI a client side/javascript app? Are you sure the app isn't actually making the call from your browser? Your browser running on your local machine and not in docker will not be able resolve the badderrer-api hostname.

Comment: I update the API URL as part of the build process. The UI is making a request to http://badderer-api:3000/users, so it's being set correctly. I'm just about ready to chalk this up to a "Windows" quirk.

Comment: Is your UI a client side/javascript app? Are you sure the app isn't actually making the call from your browser? Your browser running on your local machine and not in docker will not be able resolve the badderrer-api hostname.

Comment: Johan, I think that's what's going on. Derp! If you'd like to submit your comment about the browser not being able to resolve the domain name, I'll mark it as the answer