# Call to API from Angular in Nginx does not resolve Docker service name

Tags: angular, nginx, docker-compose

I have an `Angular` app running in a `NginX` `Docker` container.

The `Angular` app can make a `REST` call to another container (`Spring Boot` API `Docker`) using `localhost` as server.

```
server: string = 'localhost';
return this.httpClient.post<MyClass[]>('http://' + this.server + ':6060/files-data/list-files', request);
```

But `REST` call fails when using `Docker` service name instead.

```
server: string = 'files-service';
return this.httpClient.post<MyClass[]>('http://' + this.server + ':8080/files-data/list-files', request);
```

*using 8080 port this time as trying to resolve docker service name

Error in UI console:

`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Using default `NginX`image with default `nginx.conf`.

```
  nginx-files-ui:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-files-ui
    volumes:
      - ./files-ui/dist/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 99:80
```

Containers all run on same `Docker` network.

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: files-net
```

Modified `nginx.conf` to include resolver but no joy.

`resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;`

Any idea why I cannot make a `REST` call using `Docker` service name ?

****EDIT****

It seems Angular code running in browser is not able to resolve service names.

[Docker composed services can't communicate by service name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412367/docker-composed-services-cant-communicate-by-service-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is the very common misunderstanding when running application inside docker container, especially for browser apps :).

You can only call API using `service name` in your app if your app and the  api are **running** and **being accessed** within same network. In your case, the Angular app and your backend are running in same network,but the Angular app is being accessed from host machine, not inside container.

Detail: In current context, when you access your Angular app from browser, you're using the Angular app in host machine, in host network, not inside container anymore, your Angular app is exposed by mapping port from container to host machine. Therefore when you make an API request, it'll coming from host machine -> docker container, at that time, host machine will try to resolve `service name` in current context and of course from host machine there's no `service name`

Therefore, for all browser apps, even you deploy it using docker container, but when you call API, mostly you'll have to use `localhost:<mapped_port>` or something that resolves to host machine not inside docker container (Eg: domain name).

Comment: That's a very good and clear explanation. I should have know this as I'm relatively experienced with Docker but missed it. Bit silly. Hope my question and your explanation will save somebody else time in the future.

Comment: You're welcome, I was struggling with this problem in the early day when I worked with Docker :D

Comment: This explanation saved me. I was mapping the service name to the /api/ in the nginx.conf and was confused why it was not working because when you do a docker exec on the nginx container and do a curl to the api, it works. So thank you!